# ST-like encapsulation

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, encapsulation, phantom-types, rank-n-types

I am trying to use the type system to ensure that X can never be taken out from the monad M. I'm expecting it to work similar to `runST`, where it is impossible to mix environments from different threads.

```
data X s = X Int
type M s = State Int

newX :: M s (X s)
newX = X <$> get

eval :: (forall s. M s a) -> a
eval x = evalState x 0
```

However the following code does not cause a type error:

```
ghci> x = eval newX
ghci> :t x
x :: X s
```

Why does similar code in the ST monad throw an error and mine does not? To my understanding the `s` in the `M s a` should become bound, making the `s` in `X s` a free type variable and thereby causing an error in the type checker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enforce type abstraction, you must use `data` or `newtype`, not `type`.

An unused parameter in a `type` synonym has no effect at all:

```
type M s = State Int
```

So these are equivalent:

```
newX :: M s (X s)
newX :: State Int (X s)

eval :: (forall s. M s a) -> a
eval :: State Int a -> a
```

`eval` is not actually higher-rank.